# Website image help needed

Tags: html, css, image, height, width

We have a school project were we shall make a website. I have a "problem" with a image. It is kind of hard to explain the problem but I will try and I have uploaded a video to try to make it more understandible. What I want to do is to make a image not scale on the width when it scale on the height. At the moment when I drag the window witch makes the height change the image width changes and the picture looks realy bad. Look at this video and see for your selfs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ybm9rlast0

I want the picture to work as in gmail.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Basically, **where's your code?**

Comment: Define a width and height for the image. Like `#logo { height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden; }`

Comment: Take a look at css and the background property

Comment: @grooveplex that doesn't make the image responsive. Your suggestion doesn't work well on an `img` tag itself or a wrapper element. Poor advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the easisest route would be to use the background-size: cover; for your issue. First, create an element to host the image of your choice. In my example I've used a div and given it an id for styling purposes.

```
<body>
    <div id="resize"></div>
</body>
```

Then within the header tags simply add the following:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #resize{
            background-image: url("image-goes-here"); /*inject image here*/
            background-size: cover;
            height: 500px; /*desired height size*/
            width: 50%; /*desired width size*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! It works now! Just had to add "background-position: center;"

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how responsive images are *usually* implemented.

```css
/* Typical responsive image CSS */
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.container {
  width: 75%;
}
.left,
.right {
  float: left;
}
.left {
  width: 40%;
}
.right {
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x300/fc0/">
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    
    <p>
      Black jack lateen sail fire in the hole Arr coxswain topgallant Gold Road sloop lugger cackle fruit parley spanker. Fathom barque fore tackle fluke Shiver me timbers Sea Legs overhaul long clothes fire in the hole furl Admiral of the Black. Lateen sail rum capstan tack provost swing the lead scurvy overhaul cutlass dance the hempen jig tackle bilge rat.
    </p>
    
  </div>

</div>
```